# Some processes/sites with SSL failing to connect when using Charles Proxy

Tags: macos, ssl, charles-proxy

I have set up Charles on macOS 10.14.4 to allow proxying of all HTTP(S) traffic:

- Installed the Charles root certificate in System keychain and enabled trust for all options
- Configured macOS to use Charles as HTTP and HTTPS proxy
- Enabled SSL proxying with a wildcard for the location (`*.*`)

Browsing to most sites (either HTTP or HTTPS) works fine and traffic is captured by Charles. However, some sites (as well as OS network traffic) fails with the error `Client SSL handshake failed - Remote host closed connection during handshake`.

I don't really know what's causing this. Is it because the process/site detects the Charles MITM certificate (and is expecting a different one)? Is there any way around this?

[image: Client SSL handshake failed - Remote host closed connection during handshake]

Comment: Same situation. I think it has to do with asymmetric SSL